# How can I add a Fontello font in the SO code editor?

Tags: support

Is there a way to add a fontello font-icon in the SO code editor?

If yes, can somebody tell me how? Or point me to some tutorial/example question where I can learn it?

Comment: Uhh. Why would you need something like that?

Comment: @Oded To demonstrate a problem. I had posted this question here, added a small SSCCE as well, but I can't demonstrate the font files that I used. But somebody suggested in the comments that I need to demo this Not working on a Live webpage, so people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is that not solved by uploading the font file and giving a link to it? Adding support for web fonts is not straight forward (and may not be advisable anyways, for multiple reasons, including design, security and performance).

Comment: @Oded Firstly, thank you for the insight. Second, "uploading the font file" - where can I upload it? I can't see an option to upload a file (except images) in SO.

Comment: That's right. We won't host any random file type. I meant - upload to either a file-sharing site or your own website and share a link to those.

Answer (score 5):

There is no support to change font types in the editor.

This includes fontello or other web icons fonts.

If it was demonstrated that there was a wide need for such a feature, it might be considered.